# Consider the equation a?b?c =d

Tags: number-theory, number-property

Consider the equation a?b?c =d.
Here a, b and c are 3 distinct integers from 0 to 9 (both inclusive) and "?” represents any
signs out of “+", "-", “x” of “÷”. Note that the 2 question marks may represent the same
operation or 2 diferent operations of the 4 operations given above.

Note that you need to use the BODMAS Rule while dealing with the equations that we create
in this manner.
Find the smallest natural number that cannot be created in this manner.

I got this question from my classes. I cannot find a particular algorithm for this but by trial and error I think the answer should be 81. Can someone please let me know how to find it.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it's not 80, which can be formed as 2*5*8. Anyway, you have a finite number of choices at each position, so in theory you could just exhaustively calculate all 10*4*10*4*10 = 16,000 combinations (or more likely write a computer program to do so), then sort the distinct results and look for a gap.

Comment: Is there no way to derive a formula? I got 81 as I can't find any combination of distinct integers but is there any smaller number?

Comment: In your question you listed addition twice; I assume you meant to include division.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes it's division

Comment: When you say BODMAS, B is Brackets , but we have no Brackets here! In case we use BODMAS, then the SMALLEST is 91. 9x9+9=90 & we can not get 91.

Comment: I think you have not considered that a, b and c are given as 3 distinct integers

Comment: Ah, yes with Distinct Integers, what you got (81) is correct & user @Retudin is confirming it.

Answer (score 2):

> The highest possible number that is not a product (of three distinct numbers smaller than 10) is 7 + 8 * 9 = 79
>  80 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 5 = 8 * 2 * 5
>  81 = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 => not a product of distinct numbers smaller than 10.
>  manual checking of all numbers <79 assures 81 is the answer.